# Zend_Form submission > Resource 'controller::action' not found

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm taking over a site that's gone through several developers. The site is using Zend version 1.12.0, according to `Zend_Version::VERSION`, which is a new framework for me. On the site, there's a form class called `App_Form_Customers_Edit`, which extends `Zend_Form`. The form's action is /customers/edit, and when submitted, the method editAction of `CustomersController` is executed.

So, to create a new form, I created a new class `App_Form_Customers_EditAddress` in the same directory as `App_Form_Customers_Edit`, and set it's action to `/customers/editaddress`, created a function called `editaddressAction` in the `CustomersController` class and tested the form.
But I get an error saying "Resource 'customers::editaddress' not found"

The form itself is displaying properly, and as far as I can tell I'm using the exact same pattern as the other form which works, and apart from not using the zf command, the same method prescribed here in the Zend documentation: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-form.html

What do I need to do to get my new form working? Do I need to update `.zfproject.xml`? I can't see anything in there that's related to the working form.

Here's the code for `App_Form_Customers_Edit`:

```
class App_Form_Customers_Edit extends Zend_Form
{
  public function init ()
  {
    $this->addPrefixPath('App_Form', 'App/Form/');
    $this->setMethod('post');
    // ... The rest is just calls to $this->addElement
  }
}
```

And for `EditAddress`:

```
class App_Form_Customers_EditAddress extends Zend_Form
{
  public function init ()
  {
    $this->addPrefixPath('App_Form', 'App/Form/')
         ->setMethod('post')
         ->setAction('/customers/editaddress');

    $this->addElement('submit', 'active', ['value' => 'Activate']);
    $this->addElement('submit', 'remove', ['value' => 'Remove']);
    $this->addElement('hidden', 'id');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for acl declarations. If you are using acl and you have not declared rules for the action, you might get this type of error.

Comment: YES! That was it. Took me a while to find it where he had defined the resources, in the database. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Best guess:**

Your former developer has implemented a custom route somewhere. Probably in the *application.ini* or the *boostrap.php*. This custom route is looking for specific urls and `/customers/edit` conforms to a valid route but `/customers/editaddress` does not.

I think this is likely because your error is a missing resource rather then a 'page not found' or a missing controller or missing action message. So it seems as though the router is trying to match an invalid resource to a valid route.

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks. That didn't end up being the case, but I really appreciate your time anyway.